# LangChain DocArrayInMemorySearch AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'page_content'

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm running VS Code on a Mac with the Jupyter extension and having difficulty seeing the variables.

The JUPYTER: VARIABLES tab appears, along with variables, when the notebook is run. However, there's no way to drill down into the variable, which is needed if its value is long. No data viewer button appears on the left. Double-clicking do anything.

I can't find anything in settings.json that would affect this. I've ruled out extensions, except MS Jupyter itself, which is needed for Intellsense I think.

Any ideas?

Probably not related, but maybe... the Jupyter Interactive Window, it says No kernel connected, even though it shows the venv on the row immediately above. All of this can be seen in the attached image[image]